# Overwriting a variable, that already has a value assigned, with the input() function in python3

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the python code repeatedly ask for input every iteration in a while loop. I'm doing that by assigning a string value to a variable using the input() function each iteration in the loop. But the problem arises when the second iteration occurs. My code is trying to use the input function again on the same variable, which triggers an exception. (the first iteration works fine)

This is the part of my code that is not working:

```
while True:
    input = input().upper()
    text = "\n"
  
    for i in range(5):
        for char in input:
            text += letters[char][i]
        text += "\n"
        
    print(text)
```

When I run the code, this exception occurs (I don't understand why this is a problem for the input() function):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    input = input().upper()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: so the first step would be to never name your variables the same name as built-in functions or generally try to avoid naming a variable the same name as a function

Comment: Don't call your string `input`.

Comment: `input = input().upper()` clobbers the function

Answer (score 3):

`input = input().upper()` creates a variable named `input` in the current module that shadows the name `input` in the built-in scope. The built-in function is still available, but you would need to use the `builtins` module to access it. Note:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> input
<built-in function input>
>>> input = input().upper()
foo
>>> input
'FOO'
>>> input is builtins.input
False
>>> builtins.input
<built-in function input>
```

Use a different name for the return value of the built-in function. For example,

```
input_str = input().upper()
```